# IOS beta app (1.1.0.109) crashes on IOS 8

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Apple has released the newly minted IOS 8 to the wild and the current beta version of the IOS app crashes hard. I have 1.1.0.109 installed in a 64GB iPhone 5 (not 5S).

Details from phone:

```
{bundleID":"com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod","app_name":"Stack Exchange","share_with_app_devs":false,"name":"Stack Exchange","app_version":"1.1.0","is_first_party":false,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.0 (12A365)","bug_type":"109","slice_uuid":"f8ad1fe0-2109-3316-97ee-ff5a5b01c30d","build_version":"1.1.0.109","adam_id":0}
Incident Identifier: 2CAF6DFC-EC3A-4C8D-B574-DE9994D49750
CrashReporter Key:   bd0e33791e350ab7dc3f0e2834b4038a2ad624e8
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             Stack Exchange [214]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/260B04FE-96E7-4F8C-A5EF-0B8264B2F0F4/Stack Exchange.app/Stack Exchange
Identifier:          com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod
Version:             1.1.0.109 (1.1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-17 16:43:26.442 -0400
Launch Time:         2014-09-17 16:43:26.362 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A365)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/260B04FE-96E7-4F8C-A5EF-0B8264B2F0F4/Stack Exchange.app/Stack Exchange
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/260B04FE-96E7-4F8C-A5EF-0B8264B2F0F4/Stack Exchange.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00AF7000, size=0x001A4000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/260B04FE-96E7-4F8C-A5EF-0B8264B2F0F4/Stack Exchange.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  Dyld Version: 353.5

Binary Images:
0x1fed1000 - 0x1fef4fff dyld armv7s  <fd3fef9c43c9382e8e46d5d59fb52f86> /usr/lib/dyld
0x241ac000 - 0x241acfff Accelerate armv7s  <3b40c742a7323214a5eb836630536bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x24828000 - 0x2484efff Accounts armv7s  <cf7ceabb9af233f0b657f23423988703> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2484f000 - 0x2484ffff AdSupport armv7s  <e8991cf968f936d7bcc5ae162b5ede1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x24850000 - 0x248c0fff AddressBook armv7s  <eeeabdf6b9703b4f846b672d0bb50eeb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x249e6000 - 0x249f7fff AssetsLibrary armv7s  <d27e1752e7dc374e939dcf899afd47e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x24f58000 - 0x250dffff CFNetwork armv7s  <79b211df401f377fb05acc07a57db3ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x251f7000 - 0x25402fff CoreData armv7s  <db7e2287362438249bb753788c64a2b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x25403000 - 0x2572ffff CoreFoundation armv7s  <a76fd43513ee3af9af444082a92ad639> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x25730000 - 0x2585afff CoreGraphics armv7s  <a3d08c6b246236fd9a078619f6c2010b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x25bba000 - 0x25c11fff CoreLocation armv7s  <1153f2e6bde036f4b611833aa85dd9ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x25cde000 - 0x25d9efff CoreMotion armv7s  <0e91543dde123205bbfb0eec336f82e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x25d9f000 - 0x25dfdfff CoreTelephony armv7s  <32757860a7b23ee6b10cdfb2bcb5e5b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x25dfe000 - 0x25ec5fff CoreText armv7s  <4be50da4f4d13b59b32ca55d4660e5c5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x26147000 - 0x26349fff Foundation armv7s  <fadfe1d878803b27a0683288c1c7948b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x26480000 - 0x266c1fff ImageIO armv7s  <5cd6989e5626302aa49787b87e78ce32> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x26cec000 - 0x26ec5fff MediaPlayer armv7s  <2fbb4a5dc62938f999bd72c93b9f5a50> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x2736a000 - 0x273f9fff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <5e571169affe3b1f97863142d3438da5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x283bf000 - 0x28511fff QuartzCore armv7s  <4a753d93b6033495b66178dd7535fd96> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x28754000 - 0x28794fff Security armv7s  <52c6a10cc12c33cda98ce09e002c6a35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x28795000 - 0x2880dfff Social armv7s  <7b470790c7b931feb5f9b338082d6547> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x28938000 - 0x28994fff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <0dfa14680b583dd2994e2cc0563ebd53> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x28997000 - 0x2922ffff UIKit armv7s  <5e0a38c7a0a33afc9e0e51edbdc2e8f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3225e000 - 0x3225ffff libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <916c64d9cab33b2a9bbb355f4be13a76> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3265b000 - 0x327c9fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <a9bb4dc7760e3184bec94e62a99ce135> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x32bb0000 - 0x32daafff libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <f6ae15f5da4a3ee1aa1a080c069e3a1c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x32ea0000 - 0x32f46fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <463044a8a4543b11ac70cdd88a6a4a54> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32fc7000 - 0x3307dfff libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <3c08bca3a51231749b43e35d4e627cdc> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x330a0000 - 0x330acfff libz.1.dylib armv7s  <b261d154b0633244af8249c457f13def> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Comment: I just did another build.  Can you try downloading and see if it works?

Comment: @BrianNickel - Downloaded, nope, same error diagnostics.

Comment: That's insane.  Swift is working on my iOS7 32-bit device.  Why wouldn't it load on an iOS8 32-bit device?  I'll try updating the build server from GM but that's shocking since GM could be used for store builds.

Comment: Possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib

Comment: https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/

Comment: Just found that last one.  Going to give it a try.

Comment: Happy to test here. I'm in TL if you want to take it there.

Comment: @BrianNickel most recent build seems good, commenting with it now.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed! Needed to generate a new code signing certificate and then fumble around in the build server.

Comment: Indeed, version 1.1.0.117 Works For Me. :-)

Comment: Yep, all is now good

Comment: Nice to see a quick fix!